# ParcelForce : How to get test credentials for testing web services in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I'm trying to test ParcelForce as a custom shipping carrier in Magento 2..However I need testing credentials (Username & Password) to check whether I get a response from the server..  I'm finding no way to register with ParcelForce for obtaining the credentials..  Is there any way to test the web service APIs of ParcelForce with Magento ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kartik You will not get test credentials unless and until you have contract with ParcelForce. Your contract should be through customer. As per customer's requirements ParcelForce will provide test credentials. Contact on this number +44 (0) 1908 687000 :)

Comment: Can u pls also share the email address of ParcelForce support.

Comment: ParcelForce Support Email : customer.solutions@parcelforce.co.uk

Comment: any extension for parcel force shipping method ?